# Wordpress Best way to call a page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

What is the best way to call a php page? I recently decided too hard code my nav but when I try calling the page it comes back with an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/testSite.co.za/testSite.co.za/wp-content/themes/theme/companyhistory.php on line 6
```

Code:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href='http://www.testSite.co.za/' >Home</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>About us</a>
           <ul class="subnav">
<li><a href='http://www.testSite.co.za/wp-content/themes/theme/companyhistory.php'>Company History</a></li>
      </ul>
</li></ul></div>
```

**Question:**
What is the best way to call a relative page for nav in WordPress?

- plugin /which one ?
- Use full reference e.g. www.testSite.com/home/testSite.co.za/wp-content/themes/theme/companyhistory.php
- Any other options would be great :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_permalink` this will work with permalinks too and therefore is dynamic

```
 <div class="nav-wrap">
        <ul class="nav">
           <li><a href='http://www.testSite.co.za/' >Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>About us</a>
               <ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href='<?php echo get_permalink('page id'); ?>'>Company History</a></li> 
          </ul>
    </li></ul></div>
```

REFER HERE FOR MORE :
[GET PERMALINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Comment: Thanks :), how would I get the page Id ? do I have too assign it then use it ?

Comment: tell me what you exactly want to achieve . i might help you

Comment: all I wanted too do is add a drop down menu with css :| ...Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a deeper look at answers from cfgm and Diederik van den Burger. That is the right way to do that. If you want to get page id, go to all pages and mouse over the page title which you want to get the id, you can see a url at bottom of your browser. check this screenshot http://i40.tinypic.com/kc10yx.jpg . you may also check <?php wp_list_pages(); ?> @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: THANKS finally, I just tried it right now. and worked perfectly. I will use this method in the future. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't at all the way Wordpress was intended to be used.
As cfgm says, you should use a Wordpress page indeed. I would suggest to create a page "Company History" with a company-history slug, and then you can put a "page-company-history.php" in your template directory. Wordpress will then automatically use that PHP file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :), all I wanted too do is add a drop down menue with css :| ... could you show me how too implement a slug or point me too tutorial that I could learn from ?

Comment: The slug is created by Wordpress automatically. But that doesn't matter when you just want to create a dropdown menu. You're saying it yourself: this is done with CSS. Wordpress hasn't necessarily got anything to do with that. Maybe if you show us some of your code we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

A useful function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory()./companyhistory.php; ?>">
```

But why aren't you using a **Wordpress page**? If you create a page with the slug 'companyhistory', then just `<a href="/companyhistory">` is sufficient.